# Image isn't displaying in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

My image is located in appName/public/images/brand.svg

And the file I am working in is appName/views/main.ejs

And my image source is

```
<img src='../../public/images/brand.svg'>
```

or

```
<img src='../public/images/brand.svg'>
```

I don't know why it is not working. There is 'NOT FOUND' error. Is it because my path route is wrong or sth with svg file? I use chrome browser to see results. I checked for spellings errors and everything seems fine.

Comment: I think there is not enough info, what's the server config, are you using webpack? Maybe file resolver is not configured properly then?

Comment: I think default if you put the file in public file you just need to use : src="images/brand.svg"

Comment: src='images/brand.svg' doesn't work eather

Comment: I totally agree with @lukasz, the information you provided is not enough. your public folder should be inside your `src` folder. Also you can check to see if you have access to the file via typing the path into the browser from where you are, for example if your browser is running on `localhost:8000` your image should be accessible via `http://localhost:8000/public/images/brand.svg` then you can access it

Comment: Did you include this one inside root file. 
application.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); I saw you used express then it help you expose the public folder

Comment: Oh, I just figured out the error and wanted to write a comment about it and saw @NghiNguyen suggesting this solution

Comment: That's great you found the problem bro

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your CSS file.

```
body {
  background-image: url("yourimage.jpg");
}
```

Comment: The issue here is not CSS vs HTML, but rather what the URL of the image is.